# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I moved from npm to yarn and for some reason, although I imported the react-native library it doesn't recognize it, I get the error:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in '/var/react-projects/gymgains/src'
```

I delete the package.json.lock, also yarn.lock and tried again:

```
yarn
```

Yet it didn't solve the problem.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-firebase-file-uploader": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.58.5",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

And here is my import statements:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import FileUploader from 'react-firebase-file-uploader';
```

Is there a difference between running it with 'yarn start' to see it in the browser and push it to an Android to test it in the simulator, could that be the problem that react-native does not work in the web browser? 
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: How does your import code look like? What's inside your `node_modules` folder?

Comment: Hi, I just added the import statements, regarding the node_modules, all the libraries imported are there. Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had some very similar issue:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native'

and in my case it helped me to do

```
yarn add react-native-web
```

As you do not have that module installed. You could give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try `npm install` and see. I think your node_modules does not have `react-native` package.